# xpath can not get nodes with namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a huge xml document. When I test with xpath = //requestHeader  returned result is below:

```
  <requestHeader> 
      <!--Optional:-->  
      <req:clientCode xmlns:req="http://www.ibb.com/ws/requestHeader">?</req:clientCode>  
      <!--Optional:-->  
      <req:clientUsername xmlns:req="http://www.ibb.com/ws/requestHeader">CC</req:clientUsername>  
      <!--Optional:-->  
      <req:channel xmlns:req="http://www.ibb.com/ws/requestHeader">?</req:channel>  
      <!--Optional:-->  
    </requestHeader>
```

And more, I need to get clientUsername value. Unfortunately //requestHeader//req:clientUsername returns empty string. what is wrong with it?

You can test with:
http://www.xpathtester.com/test

Comment: Have you specified the namespace context for `req` in you parser?

Comment: No, how can specify it?

Comment: Depends on the API to the XPath engine you are using, which you haven't specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `req` in the `namespaceContext`:

[XPath.setNamespaceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29)

Answer (score 0):

put your namespace at the top the xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<requestHeader  xmlns:req="http://www.ibb.com/ws/requestHeader"> 
  <!--Optional:-->  
  <req:clientCode>?</req:clientCode>  
  <!--Optional:-->  
  <req:clientUsername>CC</req:clientUsername>  
  <!--Optional:-->  
  <req:channel>?</req:channel>  
  <!--Optional:-->  
</requestHeader>
```

now you can use xpath like so

```
 //requestHeader/req:clientUsername
```